# How to set max length validation on textbox using combobox selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, maxlength

In my project used 1 ComboBox and 1 textbox, in ComboBox multi byte length available like 8,12,15,20,25,30 etc.

If user select ComboBox 12Byte at the same time in text box user allow only 12byte in text box and after change 20 byte so user allow 20 byte data in text box at run time.

How to set max length validation on textbox using Combobox selection.

Comment: It depends on which Validation Method you have used or want to use!
What have you tried? and provide the code you have written.

Comment: I tried my side like this textbox.MaxLength = Convert.ToInt16(combobox.Text) * 2; working first time but next time combo box not working to set max length.

Comment: this is a pretty broad subject - it really all depends on character encoding

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="LengthComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Lengths}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox MaxLength="{Binding ElementName=LengthComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

`Lengths` items should be of type `int`

This is direct `Binding`. If you need some calulation, you have to use `Converter`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ComboBox x:Name="LengthComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Lengths}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox MaxLength="{Binding ElementName=LengthComboBox, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

---------------

public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is not int)
                return value;

            return (int)value * 2;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

PS: `Lengths` is a Property of the `ViewModel` behind the `View`

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new VM()
            {
                Lengths = new List<int>()
                {
                    1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 30
                }
            };
        }
```